# MYSQL: adding values based on string values in other cells

Tags: mysql, sql, adminer

Let's say we have table like this:

| Car | Colour | Red colour car price | Black colour car price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Brand1 | Red | 20000 | 25000 |
| Brand2 | Red | 32000 | 34000 |
| Brand2 | Black | 32000 | 34000 |
| Brand2 | Black | 32000 | 34000 |

There is set prices for 2 different colours for each car brand. Prices are different for each brand. I need to find how much different brand cars cost in total. So, for Brand1 it'll be 20000 and for Brand2 32000 + 34000 + 34000 = 100000

Final table should look like this:

| Car | Total cost |
| --- | --- |
| Brand1 | 20000 |
| Brand2 | 100000 |

I don't know how to do that and any help is welcome.

Comment: Hint: `SUM` and `Case`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select car,
       sum(case when color = 'Red' then red_color_price
                when color = 'Black' then black_color_price
           end)
from t
group by car;
```